# arr.splice() is timing out in loop - better way to replace arr[i]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

So I am having an issue with my solution, and I may be entirely off on what needs to be done. I keep timing out which makes me believe I have the .splice() in an incorrect location.

**The problem:**

> You are given an array of integers. On each move you are allowed to increase exactly one of its element by one. Find the minimal number of moves required to obtain a strictly increasing sequence from the input.

**Example**

> For inputArray = [1, 1, 1], the output should be
>   arrayChange(inputArray) = 3.

**My Pseudo code**

> First check and see if the current index is greater than the next index. If not, continue check through the entire loop. If so, add one to the next index and test again until true. If you increment the next index by one, add one to a variable "moves". Return moves

```js
function arrayChange(inputArray) { 
    
    for( var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
        var addition = (inputArray[i+1]+1)
        if(inputArray[i] >= inputArray[i+1]){     
           inputArray.splice(i,0, addition);
        }
    }
    return inputArray;
}
```

**My Error:**

> Execution time limit exceeded on test 1: Program exceeded the execution time limit. Make sure that it completes execution in a few seconds for any possible input.

Comment: `var inputArrayClone = inputArray.slice()`  use array independent of the loop or update the index

Comment: Your problem does not require any changes to myArray...

Comment: @Jonasw interesting.. I'll look into ways to test without changing the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your code fails:

```
for( var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){//iterate until reaching end of array
    var addition =(inputArray[i+1]+1);
    if(inputArray[i] >= inputArray[i+1]){  //if its not increasing   
       inputArray.splice(i,0, addition);
    }
}
```

Lets examine a sample input:

```
arrayChange([1,1]);
```

So inputArray[i] is 1, and inputArray[i+1] is 1. 
Therefore it will go into the if, as 1>=1. So it will add *1+1* into the array,but not at the end but at i, so at position 0. It will look like this:

```
[2,1,1]
```

The loop will go on:

```
[2,2,2....,1,1]
```

It will never end.

To make it work, you must stop at array.length-1 :

```
for( var i = 0; i < inputArray.length-1; i++){
```

and you must insert at the right index,and also remove one:

```
inputArray.splice(i+1,1,addition);
```

---

Non array changing approach:

```
function numchanges(array){
  var before=array[0],counter=0;
  for(var i=1;i<array.length;i++){
    if(before>=array[i]){
      //we need to change array[i] to before+1, so:
      counter+=(++before)-array[i];
    }else{
     before=array[i];
   }
  }
return counter;
}

console.log(numchanges([1,1,1]));//should return 3
```

---

How it works:
A proper *strictly monotonically increasing* function would have values like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,10]
```

So it might at least go one up, or it jumps up. So lets take one random array, and its valid counterpart:

```
[1,1,3,4,5,-1]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

So the changes needed:

```
[0,1,0,0,0,7] => 8
```

So the upper code keeps the valid number ( *before* ) and the needed change while iterating from left to right. current starts with the first array item:

```
before=array[0];//1
```

But we dont need to change the first array element, so we start at i=1.If this number is valid, so

```
before<array[i]
```

we just go on:

```
before=array[i];
i++;//due the for loop
```

If not, its not valid and we need a correction.

```
result+=before+1-array[i];
```

So if the last was 5 (*=before*) and now weve got -10 (*=array[i]*), we need to correct it to 6 (*=before+1*);

```
result+=6--10//==16
```

So we need another 16 corrections...

Comment: I tried this, and it returned null at first so I added return counter; which worked for array of [1,1,1] but failed the other tests, including: Input:
inputArray: [-1000, 0, -2, 0]
Output:
0
Expected Output:
5

Comment: Thank you!! Would it be too much to ask you to explain why it works? I apologize, I am still learning and it's all on my own so when I find cool solutions I like to understand how it works.